# Issue: PouchDB Video in Android Chrome, Firefox and Opera

Tags: video, pouchdb

I have an app where I would like to "download" videos so the user can use the app offline utilising PouchDB.  In other words I'm attempting to store videos using PouchDB and display them whilst offline.

I have an issue in Android Chrome, Firefox and Opera where the videos are stored in IndexedDB by PouchDB but they are not displayed.  The error manifests itself with either a blank video component or a message in Firefox stating "Video can't be played because the file is corrupt".

I have tried inspecting the IndexedDB utilising Chrome and Android Chrome but everything looks correct.  I have also put logging in the callback methods to find errors but no errors are thrown.

Has anyone else come across any errors like these?

Thanks

Comment: Can you set up a live example somewhere? (E.g. using http://bl.ocks.org)?  It's possible that this is a browser bug or a PouchDB bug, but it's hard to tell from your description.

Also which version of Pouch are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! bl.ocks.org looks useful.  I have put my files up there, I couldn't work out how to include videos but this should give a good idea.  The url is http://goo.gl/W05hbq

Comment: cool, I filed an issue: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/2909

Comment: @ChristopherGrigg in the demo the videos never get downloaded because they are cross origin and CORS isn't enabled

Comment: Thanks for you response nolanlawson and calvin. This is not a cors issue, the demo shows a cors issue but as I'm re-learning HTML I cannot work out quick enough how to resolve this issue. When utilising video on my server, the issue I raised still exists. I will attempt to resolve the cors issue ASAP so the demo shows my problem exactly! :)